# Como selecionar "1" ou "2" dependendo do valor da coluna, em PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho uma coluna na minha tabela TIPOCLIENTE. Nela aparecem CPF para Pessoa Física e CNPJ para Pessoa Jurídica.

Eu gostaria que no momento do `SELECT` viessem "1" para CPF e "2" para CNPJ. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Porque você não utiliza a condicional no código mesmo, pois assim você pode criar uma função para fazer isso e chama-la quando precisar. Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a condicional CASE.

```
SELECT lista_de_campos,   
    CASE tipocliente  
        WHEN 'CPF' THEN 1  
        ELSE 2  
    END AS novo_tipo_cliente  
FROM sua_tabela;
```

Comment: Mas neste caso ele cria uma nova coluna tipo cliente.

Teria como sair na mesma?

Comment: No lugar da coluna original você coloca a expressão  CASE.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.cpf_cnpj,
       case
          when length(c.cpf_cnpj) > 11 then
           2
          else
           1
       end case
  from (
        select '12345655551' cpf_cnpj
          from dual
        union
        select '01234567000115' cpf_cnpj
          from dual) c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select decode(tipo,1,cpf,2,cnpj,null) campo
From tabela
```

Uma solução com o DECODE.
Ajudou!?

Answer (score 0):

Seria isso:

```
Select decode(TIPOCLIENTE,'CPF',1,'CNPJ',2,0) TIPOCLIENTE
  From tabela
```

No caso, o valor '0' zero, vai retornar caso o valor seja diferente de CPF ou CNPJ. Também daria para tratar para caso não encontre traga a própria coluna, mas aí tem que verificar o tipo de dado, pois como é uma string deve retornar string.